# Start second JQuery counter, if first is finished?

Tags: jquery, counter, easing

I have three jQuery counters, and the first one counts to 150. While the first one is counting, the other two should be static and just show off the value 200 (second counter) and 300 (third counter).

Right at the moment the first counter reaches 150, the second one should jump in and count from 200 and ease out at 300.

While this is happening, the first should be static at 150 and the third one at 300.

So if the second reaches 300, third one should count till it reaches 400. Second one should be static after it reached 300.

```js
$.easing.easeOutExpo = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
  return (t == d) ? b + c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) + b;
}

$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {

      duration: 8000,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }

    });



});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/tavkomann/pen/mpyBOK

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```js
$.easing.easeOutExpo = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
  return (t == d) ? b + c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t / d) + 1) + b;
}
var cnt = 0;

function count() {
  var $counter = $('.counter').eq(cnt),
    countTo = $counter.attr('data-count'),
    duration = $counter.attr('data-duration')*1000;

  $({
    countNum: $counter.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {

      duration: duration,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
      step: function() {
        $counter.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $counter.text(this.countNum);
        cnt++;
        if (cnt < $('.counter').length) {
          // replace the next counter's data-count here if you want to continue instead
          count();
        }
      }

    });

}
count()
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1.5%;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="counter" id="cnt0" data-count="150" data-duration="10">0</div>
<div class="counter" id="cnt1" data-count="85"  data-duration="20">0</div>
<div class="counter" id="cnt2" data-count="2200" data-duration="5">0</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but can I also set the duration for each counter, so for example that the first one needs 10 seconds to reach 150 and the second one needs 20 seconds? Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to ask, is it possible to set a different easing for each counter?

Comment: I do not know. I never use easing - I assume you can pass a number to the easing function

Comment: One more question, can i freeze the first counter at 100, without changing data-count?

Comment: Why would you want to? But yes you can add  `step: function() {
        if ($counter.index()==0) this.countNum =this.countNum<100?this.countNum:100; $counter.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },`

Comment: Its because https://www.bugatti.com/de/chiron/ They have a video tough...

Comment: I see. I would not know how to implement that off the top of my head

Comment: Hey, it looks exactly like the Video of the Bugatti website now, except the display of seconds under the counters. I dont know how to put this text under the counters when they hit 100, 200, 300, 400?

Comment: `complete: function() {
        $counter.text(this.countNum+'<br/>secs');`

Comment: if(countNum = 100){$counter.html(this.countNum+'<br/>secs'); Why doesnt this work? The seconds only show up when all counters are finished.